# Optimización de PHP para enviar multiples datos en un formulario

Tags: php, sql, oracle

estoy trabajando en un formulario con HTML y PHP, el usuario debe ingresar un numero de DNI y después se ejecutara una query, si es solo uno no hay problemas. Pero si el usuario poner mas de un dato el sistema se demora 5 minutos en ejecutar la query, lo intente input y con textarea y el resultado es el mismo. el formulario esta en mismo archivo php

Este es el formulario

```
        <p style=color:red>Modulo en proceso de construcción</p>
        <h2>Modificar estado de médico</h2>
        <form method="GET" action="../Object/Medico/ProgramarAnulacion.php">
        <p>Ingrese el rut del médico (sin puntos ni dígito verificador, ej: 26.315.162-5 = 26315162)</p>
        <textarea class="FormManual" name="rut_medico" id="rut_medico" type="text" value="" placeholder = "Rut" required></textarea><br>
        <p>Estado:</p>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipo" id="validacion" value= "V" required>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="validacion" value= "V" required>(V) Vigente</label><br>

        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipo" id="anulacion" value= "A" required>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="anulacion" value= "A" required>(A) Anulación</label><br>
        <p>Seleccione una opción (obligatorio)</p>
        <button name="submit_modificar" type="submit" class="botones" style="background: #ff5b0c;color: #ffffff;font-size: 13px;display: block;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px 15px 6px 15px;border-radius: 3px;border: none;">Enviar</button>
        </form>';
```

Este es el PHP

```
function modificarEstado(){

if(isset($_GET["submit_modificar"])) {

    $rut_medico = $_GET["rut_medico"];
    $tipo = $_GET["tipo"];

    $sql_conexion = new sql_functions();
    $sql = "UPDATE t_usuario SET estado = '$tipo' WHERE RUT in ($rut_medico)";
    $result = $sql_conexion->updateQuery($sql, null, true);}
```

Hay una forma de que la enviar mas de un "rut_medico", la aplicacion no tarde 5 minutos en ejecutar la query?
muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Efrain , esto parece un problema de rendimiento ¿Estas usando docker, tu pc tiene un hardware poco potente, te estas conectando a una base de datos gratis en producción? este último al ser gratis la mayoría de hosting te asignan un hardware muy lento y por eso las queries suelen tardar bastante.

Comment: Intentaste que el `rut_medico` sea un array separados por `;` cada valor y en el php recorres ese array `while` y en el query no usas `RUT in` sino `RUT =`?

Comment: Hola ivandez, si estoy usando docker en un mi pc, aun no lo pruebo en el servidor

Comment: Buenas, aclarame una duda, esto es SQL o MySQL ?? Y por que estás haciendo un `WHERE IN` en vez de un `WHERE =` ??

Comment: La bd es oracle, estoy usando "in" por si el usuario pone mas de un dato

Comment: Por cuantos médicos puede consultar el usuario a la vez ???

Comment: Por muchos, solo he probado con 3 y se demora 5 minutos la consulta, lo otro seria dejar que el usuario lo haga uno por uno

Comment: Si comparas la consulta en la BD, se produce el mismo problema ?? Cuanta es la diferencia del uso de IN para varios medicos, y el uso de = para un medico ??